# How to export excel file (xlsm format) with libXL library

Tags: ios, libxl

In my iOS application, I want to generate the excel(.xlsm) file.
I used the libXl library.(http://www.libxl.com/)
This library can support Excel 97 -2003 formats (xls) and Excel 2007-2013 xml formats (xlsx/xlsm) by referencing in the home page.
Now my problem is I can export xlsx file fomat but cannot export the xlsm application in my application .
Do you know how to do this?

Comment: What does their documentation say about Macros?

Comment: You can reference with this link.                                      http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/LibXL-Changelog-63487.html

Comment: That is your job :). I'm just asking you to read the documentation for the lib that you are using.

Comment: I think this library can support micro by their documentaion.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use libXL to create macros, but you can preserve existing macros. I.e. you can take an excel macro-enabled file as a template, read it with libXL, make some modifications and save.

To save .xslm rather than .xslx you only need to give the file a different extension. File format is the same. Excel won't open an .xlsx file if it has embedded macros, but it's only a convention.